# LVM on RAID 5: LV does not mount at boot, need fsck

Tags: linux, debian, lvm, fsck, raid5

I am using Debian 11.

I have a mdadm RAID 5 array of 5 disks (4 active, 1 spare) used as a PV for a VG in which 2 LVs have been created : one for home, one for backup.

The home LV mounts at every boot, no problem. The backup LV doesn't, boot process hangs a bit on fsck then fails. I have to go in emergency mode, run fsck manually as root on the backup LV (it seems to try and correct lots of inodes), reboot and then everything boots fine.

I have been trying to look at the smartctl output for each disk but all have Reallocated_Sector_Ct or Current_Pending_Sector at 0.

Has anybody got any idea ? Let me know what outputs you need. Thanks a lot.

Edit: so, yeah, after checking my `/etc/fstab`, the backup LV was mounted after the swap and the ODD, whereas the home LV was mounted before these. I tried to move the backup LV right after the home LV, before swap and ODD, and the problem disappeared. Problem solved, thank you all for the help.

Edit2 : nope, problem still here after a regular shutdown. So as asked:

dmesg

```
[    1.388548] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    1.388556] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.388558] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.388578] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.388603] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[    1.388631] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    1.388633] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.388643] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.388646] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.388659] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    1.388661] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.388662] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.388667] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    1.388668] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.388670] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    1.388672] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.388672] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[    1.388674] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.388676] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[    1.388678] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.388683] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    1.388684] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.388686] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[    1.388691] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.388694] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.388699] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.388712] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[    1.388714] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[    1.388725] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[    1.429357]  sde: sde1
[    1.429601] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.429697]  sdd: sdd1
[    1.429869] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.430626]  sdb: sdb1
[    1.430853] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.441422]  sda: sda1
[    1.441590] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.450143]  sdc: sdc1
[    1.450331] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.531633] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.531644] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.594613] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.868769] md/raid:md0: device sda1 operational as raid disk 3
[    1.868771] md/raid:md0: device sdd1 operational as raid disk 2
[    1.868772] md/raid:md0: device sdc1 operational as raid disk 0
[    1.868772] md/raid:md0: device sde1 operational as raid disk 1
[    1.869107] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[    1.892978] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 11720288256
[   33.846459] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
```

Comment: First of all, can you usefully comment out the line in `/etc/fstab` that tries to mount your backup LV please. That'll at least allow your system to boot "normally". What filesystem is it you're using for the backup LV?

Comment: Have a look at `dmesg | less` and look for messages about this problem. Add those to your question.

Comment: @roaima commenting allows to boot "normally" as expected. I used ext4 as filesytem. I also noted while reviewing my `/etc/fstab` this backup LV is listed after the swap and ODD, whereas the home LV is listed before. I don't know if it is supposed to have an impact.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I have added what you asked.

Comment: The  order of entries in `/etc/fstab` is only relevant when there are filesystems mounted on top of other filesystems. (For example, with `/home`, `/var`, and `/var/spool`, I would expect `/var/spool` to be placed after `/var`.)

Comment: @roaima This is not true for modern systems any more as `fstab` is not handled by `mount` any more but parsed by `systemd-fstab-generator`. The Systemd mount units are ordered in the ("obviously") right way automatically.